# Dockerrun.aws.json structure for ECR Repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are switching from Docker Hub to ECR and I'm curious how to structure the Dockerrun.aws.json file to use this image. I attempted to modify the name as `<my_ECR_URL>/<repo_name>:<image_tag>` but this is not successful. I also saw the details of private registries using an authentication file on S3 but this doesn't seem like the correct route when `aws ecr get-login` is the recommended way to authenticate with ECR.

Can anyone point me to how I can use an ECR image in a Beanstalk Dockerrun.aws.json file?

If I look at the ECS Task Definition,there's a required attribute called `com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth`, but I'm not setting that anywhere in my `Dockerrun.aws.json` file and I'm not sure what needs to be there.  Perhaps it is an S3 bucket?  Something is needed as every time I try to run the Elastic Beanstalk created tasks from ECS, I get:

```
Run tasks failed
Reasons : ATTRIBUTE
```

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

**Update** I see from some other [threads](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=680534) that this used to occur with earlier versions of the ECS agent but I am currently running `Agent version 1.6.0` and `Docker version 1.7.1`, which I believe are the recommended versions. Is this possibly an issue with the Docker version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it turns out, the ECS agent was only able to pull images with version 1.7, and that's where mine was falling. Updating the agent resolves my issue, and hopefully it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely an issue with IAM roles if you are using a role that was previously created for Elastic Beanstalk. Ensure that the role that Elastic Beanstalk is running with has the **AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly** managed policy attached

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_IAM_policies.html

Comment: I suspected that as well but the IAM policy for the Beanstalk user has full AWS access, and is included in the ECR permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Support for ECR was added in [version 1.7.0](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/blob/v1.7.0/CHANGELOG.md#170) of the ECS Agent.

Answer (score 2):

When using Elasticbeanstalk and ECR you don't need to authenticate. Just make sure the user has the policy `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly`

> You can store your custom Docker images in AWS with Amazon EC2 Container Registry (Amazon ECR). When you store your Docker images in
>   Amazon ECR, Elastic Beanstalk automatically authenticates to the
>   Amazon ECR registry with your environment's instance profile, so you
>   don't need to generate an authentication file and upload it to Amazon
>   Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3).
>
> You do, however, need to provide your instances with permission to
>   access the images in your Amazon ECR repository by adding permissions
>   to your environment's instance profile. You can attach the
>   AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly managed policy to the instance
>   profile to provide read-only access to all Amazon ECR repositories in
>   your account, or grant access to single repository by using the
>   following template to create a custom policy:

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html