# How do I integrate AWS CodePipeline with Elastic Container Registry?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I have a build process where I would like to do the following

1. Trigger a Jenkins job that pulls code from github, builds a docker container and pushes it to AWS ECR
2. Run tests
3. Pull said docker container and deploy it to elastic beanstalk contingent on

It is step 3 where I am having the most trouble. I cannot find any documentation on how to connect code pipeline to ECR and then deploy a multi-container application to Elastic Beanstalk. What type of action would I need to connect to ECR and pull a container for deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling docker image should be part of your EB deployment package, Below are the reference from the official documentation. Also, See this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520548/dockerrun-aws-json-structure-for-ecr-repo).

[Multicontainer Docker Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html)

> A Dockerrun.aws.json file is an Elastic Beanstalk–specific JSON file
>   that describes how to deploy a set of Docker containers as an Elastic
>   Beanstalk application

[Using Images from an Amazon ECR Repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html)

> Elastic Beanstalk automatically authenticates to the Amazon ECR
>   registry with your environment's instance profile, so you don't need
>   to generate an authentication file and upload it to Amazon Simple
>   Storage Service (Amazon S3).

Comment: To appeal to a broader audience, what if elastic beanstalk was not used?